# How to set a Java remote developer environment in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, remote-server

My friend and me want to explore an `Open Source ERP System`. We have installed it on a server and we access it by an `IP address` over `Firefox`. We're also accessing it over the tools putty (for doing changes like restarting tomcat) , Filezilla (for import export of data), pgAdmin (for accessing the psql db). Now we want to establish a java Eclipse developer environment on both our windows pcs working simultaneously. I need to access, change and commit to the source placed on the server. Every time I commit, I need to deploy the source code with putty.

1) Is there a better way of this way of remote programming? If yes, could you tell me a better way?

2) If not, how can I set this kind of environment in Eclipse (Create an existing project?)

Comment: I don't know about Eclipse, but IntelliJ has a feature that allows me to connect to a remote host and synch up code with it.  There's a community edition.

Answer (score 0):

You need configure [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) Which will deploy the latest code into remote server

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to automate your deploy